# Order of a pole formula / definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I have come up with the following formula for the order of a pole of some function $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ at a point $z = c$. It involves first taking the multiplicative inverse (denoted by $1/f(z)$ to avoid getting mixed up with the inverse of the function), then finding the smallest $n$ such that the derivative is not equal to zero.

$$
\operatorname{ord}(f, c)=\min \{ n \in \mathbb N:(1/f)^{(n)}(c)\neq 0 \}
$$

Does this equation hold? It works for my naive test of $f((z-2)^{-3}, 2)$. However I haven't seen it written in my course notes. Is it also true that the order of a pole is the algebraic multiplicity wrt to the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this formula holds.

Indeed, suppose that $f(z)$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z = c$. Then $1/f(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z = c$.

So the Taylor expansion of $(1/f)(z)$ around $z = c$ takes the form
$$(1/f)(z) = a_n (z - c)^n + a_{n+1} (z - c)^{n+1} + a_{n+2} (z - c)^{n+2} + \dots $$
with $a_n \neq 0$.

It follows that
$$ \left( 1/f\right)(c) = \left( 1/f\right)'(c) = \left( 1/f\right)''(c) = \dots = \left(1/f\right)^{(n-1)}(c) = 0$$
and
$$ \left(1/f\right)^{(n)}(c) = n! \times a_n \neq 0.$$

Thus $n = \min \{ m \in \mathbb N : \left(1/f\right)^{(m)}(c) \neq 0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was thinking of exactly the same thing. I came up with this one. Is this good?

The formula for the order of a pole can be expressed as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sigma = \begin{cases}
    j, & \text{if } i = 1 \text{ and } N(z_0) = 0 \\
    j - i, & \text{if } i > 1 \text{ and } N(z_0) = 0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $f(z) = \frac{{(N(z))^i}}{{(D(z))^j}}$, $z$ is the variable, $z_0$ is the singularity, $i$ is the exponent of the numerator, and $j$ is the exponent of the denominator.

Comment: Would depend on what $D(z)$. Not as simple to decide for something like$f=\frac{1}{z(z-2)^3}$